Fillna with values from other rows with matching keys
In the dataframe I define below I want to use the features ID and ID2 to fill the cells of features val1 and val2 with values. I want all ID and ID2 cominations to have the same values for the features val1 and val2.

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 
              'DATE':['2021', '2022', '2023', '2021', '2022', '2023'],
              'ID2':[23, 34, 54, 321, 1244, 1244], 
              'val1':[np.nan, 200, 300, np.nan, 234, np.nan], 
              'val2':[55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, np.nan], 
              'val3':['A', 'F', 'W', 'T', 'I', 'O']})

#expected result

print(pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 
              'DATE':['2021', '2022', '2023', '2021', '2022', '2023'],
              'ID2':[23, 34, 54, 321, 1244, 1244], 
              'val1':[np.nan, 200, 300, np.nan, 234, 234], 
              'val2':[55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, 99999], 
              'val3':['A', 'F', 'W', 'T', 'I', 'O']}))


If need first non missing value per groups in columns val1 and val2 use GroupBy.transform with GroupBy.first:
df[['val1','val2']] = df.groupby(['ID','ID2'])[['val1','val2']].transform('first')
print (df)
   ID  DATE   ID2   val1     val2 val3
0   0  2021    23    NaN  55555.0    A
1   0  2022    34  200.0  66666.0    F
2   0  2023    54  300.0  77777.0    W
3   1  2021   321    NaN  88888.0    T
4   1  2022  1244  234.0  99999.0    I
5   1  2023  1244  234.0  99999.0    O


Another solution, using .ffill().bfill():
df[["val1", "val2"]] = df.groupby(["ID", "ID2"], group_keys=False)[["val1", "val2"]].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

print(df)

Prints:
   ID  DATE   ID2   val1     val2 val3
0   0  2021    23    NaN  55555.0    A
1   0  2022    34  200.0  66666.0    F
2   0  2023    54  300.0  77777.0    W
3   1  2021   321    NaN  88888.0    T
4   1  2022  1244  234.0  99999.0    I
5   1  2023  1244  234.0  99999.0    O

